# How do you setup Commerce Event Tickets?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using [Commerce 7.x-1.10](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) & [Commerce Event Tickets 7.x-1.x-dev](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_event_ticket). I have installed all the prerequisites for both modules.

How do you setup Commerce Event Tickets so it creates the **ticket entity** per unit in the order?

I have done the following to try to set this up:

1. Under Checkout Rules `admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules`, I have change the following rule `Update the order status on checkout completion` under the action of `Update the order state` to **COMPLETED**.
2. Create a custom product type.
3. Add the existing field `cet_enable` to the product type.
4. Create a product and enabled the checkbox `Enable Tickets`.
5. Create a Product Display
6. Add a product reference field to the Product Display to the product created in step 4.
7. id a test purchase to see if the ticket entity was created for the product. 
   (*This is where my process breaks down, it should create the ticket entity as this point.*)

Comment: Hm, even skipping step 1 worked out for me. After creating the first test purchase I added some custom fields, which I assume can be used for more elaborate logic. This is the module configuration page _admin/commerce/config/event-ticket_ if you want to change something. After creating the second purchase I was able to see two tickets created here _admin/commerce/tickets_. Can you check the watchdog for any error messages? Cheers!

Comment: Which branch did you use? Stable or Dev?

Comment: Commerce Event Ticket 7.x-1.0-beta2+4-dev